# How to create a new Google Doc from a downloaded Google Doc?

Tags: python, google-docs-api

Trying to make a new document from an existing one through Google Doc API with Python, I have this puzzling situation where creating a doc I just downloaded results in a document being empty (and so totally different from what I downloaded). What am I doing wrong?

```
gdoc = doc_service.documents().get(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID).execute()
doc = doc_service.documents().create(body=gdoc).execute()
```

The created document should be identical to the downloaded document

Comment: If you would like to copy an existing document, you could try to use the Google Drive API's [`files().copy`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/copy) method if you want to copy the exact downloaded Google Doc.